# Can we wrap children of ExpandableListView with a border

Tags: android, android-layout, border, expandablelistview

I have the following ExpandableListView, which contains group_item and child_items. I added margin to the child items so that I could all wrap children with a border.

[image]

I would like to know Can we wrap children of ExpandableListView with a border as below?

[image]

**Code:**

**list_group.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="55dip"
android:background="@drawable/trip_group_border"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="17dip"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="7dip"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemIndicatorRight"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:background="@drawable/trip_item_outer_border"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/trip_item_border"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textColor="@color/black2"
        android:textSize="17dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textColor="@color/black2"
        android:textSize="17dip" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this,, But, I think it is not a good solution!!

BaseExpandableListAdapter

```js
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_container, parent, false);
        View itemView = null;//The actual view
        container.addView(itemView);
        if (childPosition == 0) {
            container.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_itemblock_first);
        } else if (isLastChild) {
            container.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_itemblock_bottom);
        } else {
            container.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_itemblock);
        }
        return container;
  }
```

shape_itemblock_first

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/divider_light" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="1px" android:top="1px" android:right="1px" android:bottom="0dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

shape_itemblock_bottom.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/divider_light" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="1px" android:top="0dp" android:right="1px" android:bottom="1px">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

shape_itemblock.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/divider_light" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="1px" android:top="0dp" android:right="1px" android:bottom="0dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

layout_container.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="1px"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_itemblock"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</RelativeLayout>
```